# Celery tries to connect to the wrong broker

Tags: python, redis, celery, celeryd

I have in my celery configuration

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
```

Yet whenever I run the celeryd, I get this error

```
consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

Why is it not connecting to the redis broker I set it up with, which is running btw?

Comment: Looks like celery cannot find your configuration and uses default. Where have you put your `celeryconfig.py` file? It must be on your python path ([docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration-and-defaults)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

import your celery and add your broker like that :

```
celery = Celery('task', broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379')
celery.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
```

This code belongs in celery.py

Comment: Where would this go? I have a celery.py file which contains similar code as your answer, which is in the same folder as my settings.py. Yet I get same error as OP. Same issue when put in settings.py

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Please see my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402447/how-to-set-celeryconfig-file-in-in-django?noredirect=1#comment47060151_29402447

Comment: As far as I know `config_from_object` will overwrite `broker` given as argument to the constructor, if `BROKER_URL` exists inside celeryconfig file...

Answer (score 4):

If you followed [First Steps with Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django) tutorial, specifically:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

then you need to prefix your settings with `CELERY`, so change your `BROKER_URL` to:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this response because I was starting my celery worker incorrectly on the terminal.

I was running:

```
celery -A celery worker
```

But because I defined `celery` inside of `web/server.py`, I needed to run:

```
celery -A web.server.celery worker
```

`web.server` indicates that my `celery` object is in a file server.py inside a directory web. Running that latter command connected to the broker I specified!