# How to set celeryconfig file in in django

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, celery

[image]

I have a Django project on an Ubuntu EC2 node, which I have been using to set up an asynchronous using `Celery`. I've been trying to follow http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/

I've been able to get a basic task working at the command line, using:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO

(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO

 -------------- celery@ip-172-31-22-65 v3.1.17 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-44-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tp:0x7f66a89c0470
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

However, if I run other celery commands like below I'm getting the following:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery worker                       [2015-04-03 13:17:21,553: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py:161: 


 -------------- celery@ip-172-31-22-65 v3.1.17 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-44-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x7f1653eae7b8 (.default.Loader)
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[2015-04-03 13:17:21,571: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

It appears that celery thinks I'm using amqp as a broker , but I'm using redis!!

Based on [Celery tries to connect to the wrong broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176533/celery-tries-to-connect-to-the-wrong-broker), it seems likely that celery cannot find the configuration file and uses the default.

In the above question they recommend:

```
import your celery and add your broker like that : 

celery = Celery('task', broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379')
celery.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
```

Where would I do this? is my celery.py file (below), the same as a celery config?

/projects/tp/tp/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import django
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tp.settings')
django.setup()

app = Celery('hello_django')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.cache import cache


@shared_task
def tester1(param):
    return 'The test task executed with argument "%s" ' % param
```

tp/tp1/views

```
@csrf_exempt
def tester(request):

    tester1.delay('hi')

    return HttpResponse('hTML')
```

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/tp-celery.conf

```
[program:tp-celery]
command=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/ubuntu/projects/tp
user=ubuntu
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker-out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker-err.log

autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true
```

/var/log/celery-worker-out.log

```
 -------------- celery@ip-172-31-22-65 v3.1.17 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-44-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tp:0x7fa33e424cf8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . testapp.tasks.tester1
```

Comment: put `celery.py` aside of `settings.py`.Also change, `app = Celery('hello_django')` to `app = Celery('tp')`, if your project name is `tp`.

Comment: I changed app = Celery('tp'). What do you mean by ' put celery.py aside of settings.py'?

Comment: wherever `settings.py` there should be `celery.py`.That i mean.Then what is your project name ?.I mean `settings.py` in which folder ?

Comment: The project name is 'tp'

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the project structure

Comment: `app = Celery('tp')` still not working ?

Comment: I just thought of something, I need to reload celery after making code changes. Can I ask you how you do this?

Comment: if you are running celery using `celery --app` command, quit it(Ctrl+c) and restart it.

Comment: This time i'm not doing it that way, I'm using supervisor

Comment: First you have to setup all this without supervisor, because otherwise to find error always look into logs.

Comment: if I run celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO at the command line it works (discussed above). However the rest of the celery functions don't work. I've added more output above so you can see.

Comment: Dont run `celery woker` only..run like`celery -A tp worker -l info`.if it working on command line then what isrest of celery function?

Comment: I've modified the question to show the output, above. by 'the rest of celery function' do you mean tasks.py? I've added this above

Comment: `celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO` is working i think, then why dont you proceed to `call` tasks ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'call tasks'?

Comment: you have to call task in `tasks.py` na??For what purpose you using celery ?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. I've added code from my view above. This does work when I run a worker from the command line but not when I try to run them as a daemon using supervisor.

Comment: K thats cool..then put your supervisor script here

Comment: try different log file for error and output. `celery-worker_out.log` and `celery-worker_error.log`.Then check eror logs

Comment: I did this and restarted supervisor with sudo supervisorctl restart tp-celery

Comment: Interestingly the output is still being send to the old log. Shouldn't supervisor kill the old processes and use the new logs? sudo supervisorctl reread also doesn't change anything.

Comment: ok based on http://www.onurguzel.com/supervisord-restarting-and-reloading/ I did supervisorctl update, then started and stopped tp-celery

Comment: Now new log? after `reread` and `update`?

Comment: Now it is working i think ?what is the problem now ? check `error` log also if any error happened ?

Comment: Yes, it is working, but the original problem remains. if I run celery worker [2015-04-03 13:17:21,571: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.

Comment: Then why are you trying `celery worker` after all this working correct? i didnt understand that effort ?

Comment: Its not just celery worker ,  all the celery inspect commands give the same error. I found this out after trying your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319889/how-to-list-of-the-queued-items-in-celery

Comment: if you want that, `celery --app=tp.celery:app inspect active_queues` or simply `celery -A tp inspect active_queues`

Comment: Another thing, no need of `--app`(its not error :)), simply `celery -A tp worker --loglevel=INFO`

Comment: Ok , thank you, that works. I misunderstood the docs. Can you enter this as an answer please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dont run `celery woker` only..run like `celery -A tp worker -l info`. It will take default `config`.

For `celery inspect`

```
celery --app=tp.celery:app inspect active_queues
```

**OR simply**

```
celery -A tp inspect active_queues
```